# How to resize images in UITableViewCell?

Tags: ios, uitableview

I am trying to make an Xcode app that has a list that loads data from a JSON file. It basically has a title, subtitle, and a thumbnail image. When the app loads up, the images are exactly as big as the cells. I would either like to resize the images to a set size, or make some extra room in-between the cells. Here is my current code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"TableCell";


UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];


NSDictionary *tempDictionary= [self.googlePlacesArrayFromAFNetworking objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:[tempDictionary objectForKey:@"icon"]];
NSData *data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url];
cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageWithData:data];
CALayer * l = [cell.imageView layer];
[l setCornerRadius:13];
[l setBorderWidth:0.5];
[l setBorderColor:[[UIColor lightGrayColor] CGColor]];
cell.imageView.layer.masksToBounds = YES;
...}
```

Thanks for your help.

Update: I have discovered this:

```
 UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL :url]];

CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
[thumbnail drawInRect:imageRect];
cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

The image resizes, but it is just blank.

Comment: Why not make a custom cell, and setup the constraints on an image view to be whatever size you want?

Comment: I have already tried, however I cannot figure out what on earth happens. It's very strange. The labels I drag in are separate ones from the titles and subtitles loaded from the JSON.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "the labels I drag in are separate ones from the titles and subtitles loaded from the JSON". How are you setting the text on the labels?

Comment: Actually I discovered this:

Comment: UIImage *thumbnail = [UIImage imageWithData: [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL :url]];

    CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
    CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height);
    [thumbnail drawInRect:imageRect];
    cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
    UIGraphicsEndImageContext();

Comment: Please don't make synchronous network calls on the main thread, especially within `cellForRowAtIndexPath:`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit;
```

Or:

```
cell.imageView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFill;
```

Or, you could scale the images that you get from the url.

```
CGFloat scale = 10.0f;    // adjust this number
UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithData:
                                  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:url]
                                  scale:scale];
cell.imageView.image = image;
```

Comment: This unfortunately did not do anything. The images are still the same size. This may be because the cells are not custom cells. In the dropdown options under style, I have selected "Subtitle".

Comment: It still builds and runs, but it gives me a warning that "image" is an unused variable.

Comment: @anthonya1999 Check out the edit. You use this image in your imageView.

Answer (score 1):

I was facing same problem with image re-sizing. After searching on internet I found a useful method:

```
+(UIImage*)imageWithImage:(UIImage*)image scaledToSize:(CGSize)newSize
{
UIGraphicsBeginImageContext( newSize );
[image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0,0,newSize.width,newSize.height)];
UIImage* newImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
return newImage;
}
```

This will return the image size. 
In my case I made a Helper class and in ***Helper.h*** I declared this method as a class method so that I can call it in my UITableView. An than in ***Helper.m*** I implemented this method.

In cellForRowAtIndexPath method:

```
cell.imageView.image = [Helper imageWithImage:***Your Image here*** scaledToSize:CGSizeMake(ImageWidth,ImageHeight)];
```

Don't forget to import Helper.h in your TableView class.
You can also use this class in your way.
Hope it works.