# Should we scale image before setting it to a imageView in UITableView

Tags: uitableview, cocoa-touch, uiimageview, uiimage, image-resizing

I am displaying a list of images with names, with a chevron accessory to see the full size version of selected image.

I see that the scrolling performance is not super smooth.  I think the reason is that the image I am assigning to the imageView of each cell is the full size image (which gets scaled down automatically before display).

Will the performance improve if I maintain a smaller image that is of "thumbnail" size?  If yes, what is the best way to do this?  I see some example in [How to resize images in UITableViewCell?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25214290/how-to-resize-images-in-uitableviewcell).  Is the answer (reproduced below) that uses the approach below, good enough?

Also, any other tips to make the scrolling smoother?

```
 CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(30, 30);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
 CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(30.0, 30.0, itemSize.width,  itemSize.height);
 [thumbnail drawInRect:imageRect];
 cell.imageView.image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, scaling down image helps a lot. I created the method below to resize following (and call it on a background thread to keep main UI thread humming)

I also, found calling *reloadData* on only the row that changed helps using

```
 [self.tableView reloadRowsAtIndexPaths:[NSArray arrayWithObject:indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationNone];
```

Method used to downsize.

```
 - (UIImage *) returnThumbnail:(UIImage*)image
{
 CGSize itemSize = CGSizeMake(120, 90);
 UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(itemSize);
 CGRect imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width,  itemSize.height);
 [image drawInRect:imageRect];
 UIImage *scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
 UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
 NSLog(@"Returning scaled image %@",scaledImage) ;
 return scaledImage ;
}
```